# Can I extend Ionic's NavController?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to set the `navParams` to have an specific structure everything `.setRoot()` or `.push()` is called. For this I wanted to extend the `NavController` class like I was able to do it with Angular's `Http`

I have tried this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationProvider extends NavController {

    constructor() {
        super();
    console.log('Hello NavigationProvider Provider');
  }

}
```

But It does not work. It is because is a static class? How could I create a wrapper over the `NavController`?